# How could I query by one of multiple possible value in mongoid

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, mongoid, mongoid4

from = [:TPE, :TOKYO, :CHICHAGO]

```
where(
  from: /.*#{from}.*/i,
)
```

## Input documents

```
{
    from: 'PARIS'
},
{
    from: 'PARIS'
},
{
    from: 'TOKYO'
},
{
    from: 'TPE'
}
```

## Output documents

```
{
    from: 'TOKYO'
},
{
    from: 'TPE'
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use an [`$in` operator](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/in/) to see if a field matches anything in an array:

```
where(:from => { :$in => array })
```

Mongoid patches the MongoDB operators into `Symbol` as methods so you could also say:

```
where(:from.in => array)
```

If you really are looking for values that contain any of the values in an array then you could just build a single regex that does that using alternation:

```
re = /#{array.map { |s| Regexp.escape(s.to_s) }.join('|')}/i
Model.where(:from => re)
```

Note that there's no leading or trailing `.*` in the regex as that doesn't do anything useful. Also note the presence of `Regexp.escape` calls before the components are joined with the regex alternation operator (`|`).

Comment: Hi could regex match also could be applied in '$in' operator ?

Comment: Are you looking for pattern matching rather than strict equality?

Comment: yes! as you can see, originally i match with this way ` from: /.*#{from}.*/i,`, but i didn't know how to apply it in `$in` operator

Comment: You wouldn't bother with `$in` in that case, you'd just build a single regex as in my last update.